# Docker login to Azure Container Registry by Service Principle

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry

I've created a service principle with AcrPush role assigned. But when I access the container registry from docker it ask me user name and password. I've never set the user name and password, how can I configure the docker to user the service principle?

Comment: Why you ask the question about the service principal, but accept the answer for the admin user?! What are you thinking about?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not have to set the username and password as it is already there in the container registry. 
In the container registry, you can enable the admin mode, and that is where you get your credentials from. 
[image]

`docker login myregistry.azurecr.io`

Enter the username and password from the portal and it should work.

With [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal) if properly created, you can do the following:

```
docker login myregistry.azurecr.io --username $SP_APP_ID --password $SP_PASSWD
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer from @kgalic, you can also do the following:
You didn't specify as to *where* you're executing the docker login command, but assumingyou have access to the Azure CLI and appropriate credentials, you can log into your azure container registry via `az acr login --name <acrName>`.  This will flow the ACR credentials down to docker so that you don't need to execute a separate `docker login`

See the following for more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication

Answer (score 3):

For your issue, you use the service principal for the ACR with the role `AcrPush` to push the images. The username and the password are that appId and password of the service principal, but you need to take care that the password is only displayed once when the service principal is created. If you forget the password, you need to reset it. So the docker login would be like this:

```
docker login youracr.azurecr.io -u app_id -p app_password
```